# Building lots of similar projects with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

Our solution has got a ton of projects in it, and our MSBuild file is becoming a gigantic, unstable morass of angle brackets that has gotten so large that I've begun to be scared to touch it. However, I noticed that most of our projects fall into two groups.

There are web projects, which have a .csproj extension and are built and deployed using web deployment projects to dump them into a directory. There is also a configuration transform process. Basically, to deploy a web project, one only needs the project name, the output directory, and the config transforms.

Similarly, we have an ever-increasing number of service apps that will live under TopShelf. These are basically dlls that are built from .csproj files. Like the above websites, they undergo a config transform, but they are copied to the output directory instead of going through the web deployment steps.

It occurred to me that it would be really slick if I could simply provide the MSBuild project with a couple of text files (one for the webs and the other for the services) that MSBuild could then use to dynamically compile all the various projects. I was thinking that if I could just feed it a comma-delimited list of projects, output locations, and config replacement files that there might be a way to get msbuild to read them in, iterate over them, and dump out the projects where they are supposed to go.

However, my MSBuild-fu is weak. How do I even get started on this?

Comment: Maybe [my answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3071804/205233) can give you a head start. Basically my approach was to pack all the processing into a core MSBuild script and all project specific information into target scripts that can be imported when needed.

Comment: In your case you'd need 2 core scripts (web + services). Could you add a sample extract from your current (monolithic) MSBuild script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd419659.aspx), this is [part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx#id0100082). 
For config files I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.