# multiple hint paths in csproj file from an text file variable

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj

**Context :** 
In our application there two separate dlls which are repositories of variables configured for different types of hardware .These dlls has same name  and is referenced from our application, Now every time if we wanted to test the different type of hardware we have to copy the relevant dll to the location where application is running. I am looking for a workaround.

**References :**
I have seen the following threads ,

1) [.csproj multiple hint paths for an assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666618/csproj-multiple-hint-paths-for-an-assembly)

2) https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/conditional-project-or-library-reference-in-visual-studio/

**Question:**
Can i declare a variable in a text file say **`<hardware> type1 </hardware>`** and import that text file in my csproj file and assign the appropriate reference to my application ?

Any help ..

Following is the test application which replicates our project. SignalPool1, SignalPool2 have the same class name and are repositories for two different hardware configurations available in two different locations of our project. If we wanted to test the hardware1 we would remove the current reference and add the reference of signal pool which is relevant there same applies for hardware2. Now to avoid this manual work i wanted to automate this process either to declare a variable on XML and access the variable in csproj file to decide which to access at the time of Compilation/Running.

Currently to avoid this problem i have a separate exe which reads the xml and decides to copy them into one common folder.This exe will be called at the time of prebuild event in our project.

// Signal Pool 1 File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SignalPool
{
public abstract class SignalPool
{
    public abstract string PreExec();
    public abstract string PostExec();
    public abstract string VnVExec();

    public static string HWVar1 = "HWVar1";
    public static string HWVar2 = "HWVar2";
    public static string HWVar3 = "HWVar3";
    public static string HWVar4 = "HWVar4";
}
```

}

// Signal pool2

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace SignalPool
    {
    public abstract class SignalPool
    {
    public abstract string PreExec();
    public abstract string PostExec();
    public abstract string VnVExec();

    public static string HWVar1 = "HWVar5";
    public static string HWVar2 = "HWVar6";
    public static string HWVar3 = "HWVar7";
    public static string HWVar4 = "HWVar8";
    }
}
```

//Accessing pool Variables

Main File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestLibraries
{
    class Program 
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

        Testhardware th = new Testhardware();
        th.functionToValues();



    }

    private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("SignalPool")) //Put in the name of your assembly
        {
            //var configValue = XDocument.Parse("<config><hardware>type1</hardware></config>").Document.Descendants("hardware").First().Value;
            var configValue = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\ha23031\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestLibraries\TestLibraries\TestInfo.xml").Document.Descendants("IsRealHMI").First().Value;
            if (configValue == "false")
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\ha23031\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestLibraries\SignalPool\bin\Debug\SignalPool.dll");
            }
            else if (configValue == "true")
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Users\ha23031\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SignalPool\bin\Debug\SignalPool.dll");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestLibraries
{
    class Testhardware : SignalPool.SignalPool
    {
    public override string PostExec()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public override string PreExec()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public override string VnVExec()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public string functionToValues()
    {
        // This is how i access variables based on the loaded variables
        string s = SignalPool.SignalPool.HWVar1;
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are climbing the wrong mountain. Try going back to introduce the [Strategy Pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/285276/design-pattern-dll-per-strategy).

Comment: @TomBlodget , thanks for the reply, I think i did not made my self clear . these two dlls with the same name are not part of our development cycle these are delivered to us by two(type1 hardware, type2 hardware ) different teams .

Comment: For a real answer you'd need to define your *test*. Is it running your application in the debugger or are you running unit tests against it? The answer could be as simple as defining 2 build configurations and set according conditions on your reference.

Comment: @Filburt , i have defined test but i am not sure what should be written in *.task file and where should i define the variable i was telling about

Comment: If you are running an application, editing the csproj file is not the solution. The csproj approach is for Visual Studio, so Visual Studio knows what DLL you are looking for and compiles with that one. I believe you should be looking into Assembly.Load() during the start of your application. Instead of the application picking the DLL automatically, you force it to load the DLL you want. Create logic to read your configuration file and Assembly.Load() the DLL you want to load based on it.

Answer (score 1):

*"Can i declare a variable in a text file say  type1  and import that text file in my csproj file and assign the appropriate reference to my application ?"*

Isn't that [exactly what I describe in the blog post you link to](https://whathecode.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/conditional-project-or-library-reference-in-visual-studio/)?

Look for the defined variable '*SomeProject*' in the configuration file *'ProjectReferences.txt'* which I load from the .csproj file.

ProjectReferences.txt

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration) == 'Debug With Project References'">
    <SomeProject>..\SomeProject</SomeProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

.csproj file

```
<Import Project="..\ProjectReferences.txt" />
<Choose>
  <When Condition="Exists($(SomeProject))">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="$(SomeProject)\SomeProject.csproj">
        <Project>{6CA7AB2C-2D8D-422A-9FD4-2992BE62720A}</Project>
        <Name>SomeProject</Name>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
  <Otherwise>
    <ItemGroup>
      <Reference Include="SomeProject">
        <HintPath>..\Libraries\SomeProject.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the correct DLL during the startup of your application, before .Net loads it for you. NET will load the default DLL as soon as an instance of that class is created. So make sure to load the proper DLL first before you access the properties. Make sure you do not access these properties in the initial class anywhere as .Net will load it then.

Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //var configValue = XDocument.Parse("<config><hardware>type1</hardware></config>").Document.Descendants("hardware").First().Value;
        var configValue = XDocument.Load("MyXmlConfig.xml").Document.Descendants("hardware").First().Value;
        if (configValue == "type1")
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TEMP\MyAssembly_Type1.dll");
        }
        else if (configValue == "type2")
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TEMP\MyAssembly_Type2.dll");
        }

        MyRepositoryClass.Initialize();
    }
}

static class MyRepositoryClass
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var variable1 = MyAssembly.MyRepository.Variable1;
        var variable2 = MyAssembly.MyRepository.Variable2;
        var variable3 = MyAssembly.MyRepository.Variable3;
    }
}
```

Alternative load the DLL on demand (when .Net asks for it):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

        MyRepositoryClass.Initialize();
    }

    private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Name.Contains("MyAssembly")) //Put in the name of your assembly
        {
            //var configValue = XDocument.Parse("<config><hardware>type1</hardware></config>").Document.Descendants("hardware").First().Value;
            var configValue = XDocument.Load("MyXmlConfig.xml").Document.Descendants("hardware").First().Value;
            if (configValue == "type1")
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TEMP\MyAssembly_Type1.dll");
            }
            else if (configValue == "type2")
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TEMP\MyAssembly_Type2.dll");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi , thank you so much for the reply i have implemented the same in my application but did not worked , i think it is because it is inheriting some of the functions from that class. I have edited and added the code in the test application Please go through the code and let me know where i am making mistake

Comment: You have combined the 2 different ways to do it. Firstly the first manual loading one is failing because you are accessing the properties in the same method, which means .Net has already loaded the default DLL before you even tried to load it. Secondly you forgot to add the eventhandler that actually tells .Net to use your AssemblyResolve function. Remove the manual loading part, and only use the AssemblyResolve part. Dont forget to actually attach the eventhandler... +=

Comment: thanks for the observation Updated still did not worked . I think this assembly resolve will only execute if it didn't  resolve the dll at runtime, in my case i am adding it only at compile time "Add reference" (Because  there are functions to inherit from that class), will this be an issue ?

Comment: You should detail you solution a bit more, because what I read is that you are _running_ your application on different computers (diff hardware), meaning runtime. So either you want to load the correct DLL dynamically during running of your application OR you want to create a deployment package for each machine with your test application and the corresponding DLL.

Comment: As long as these different Assemblies are identical (same namespace and class names), dynamic loading should work, to load the one over the other. The compile time reference is only so the compiler can verify the existence of the classes/fields/properties/methods/etc. What you actually use when running the program is what you can override with dynamic loading.

Comment: Hi ,to answer to the question No application runs on one compute but different types of hardware's(one at a time) are connected to this computer for the test. These DLL's are just repositories of variables for different types of hardware's. I want correct dll to be referenced based on XML/ text file at compile/ run-time .  Please see the updated question

Comment: You problem is still that you are to early. .Net has already decided on the DLL before you tell it to use your own handler. Create a new classlibrary. Move ALL your functionality code there. Call this library from main(). Do NOT call anything of your code directly from Main. Do not have any "using" statements to your own classes from in Program.cs. As I initially wrote, .Net will load the Assemblies as soon as it needs it, and once it enters a class/function and it finds your classes ref'd there it will load it.